# Retrieving length of an array in a method doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm fairly new to Java so please imagine that I'm 5 years old and require an answer suitable for a five year old.

**First some information:**
I'm trying to make a "Dynamic array" that grows and shrinks when needed. I know of arraylists, the purpose of this is that i need to be able to do this myself and also learn at the same time since i assume this is how `ArrayList`s work anyway.

**The problem:** I want to add some fancy methods for the reason above one of which is to calculate the mean value of the whole array.
when i try to get the length (`varible.length`) so does it not work while in some other methods it does!

This is the method that doesn't work:

```
public double meanValue() {
    double meanDiv = 0;
    int div = x.length;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < div ; i++) {
        meanDiv += x[i];
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
    meanDiv = meanDiv/x.length;
    return meanDiv;
}
```

It's returning NaN (not a number), but if you skip the division part it returns 0, it's totally not reading `x.length`.

Worst part? Some methods are working, this one for example to return the last position:

```
public long last() {
    long pepe = -1;
    if (x.length==0) {
        System.out.println("Nothing in the array! Returning -1");
    }
    else {
        pepe = x[x.length-1];
    }
    return pepe;
}
```

I've tried way too many things, different kind of variables, while instead of for, etc.

Here is the whole class if it's required:

```
public class dynamicArray {
    private long[] x;
    private int size = 0;

    public dynamicArray() {
        x = new long[size];
    }                                         // CREATES THE ARRAY  

    public long grab(int x) {
        if (x < this.x.length) {
            return this.x[x];
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("(GET) Out of bounds");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public void add(long value) {
        dynamicInAction();
        x[size] = value;
        size++;
    }                                   // ADD A NUMBER TO THE ARRAY
    public void remove(int position) {

    }                              // REMOVES A SPECIFIC ARRAY POSITION----------------
    public long last() {
        long pepe = -1;
        if (x.length==0) {
            System.out.println("Nothing in the array! Returning -1");
        }
        else {
            pepe = x[x.length-1];
        }
        return pepe;
    }                                           // RETURNS THE VALUE IN THE LAST POSITION
    public long first() {
        long pepe = -1;
        if (x.length==0) {
            System.out.println("Nothing in the array! Returning -1");
        }
        else {
             pepe = x[0];
        }
        return pepe;
    }                                          // RETURNS THE VALUE IN THE FIRST POSITION
    public void modify(int position, int value) {
        if (position < x.length && position >= 0) {
            x[position] = value;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This position does not exist");
        }
    }                   // MODIFIES A SPECIFIC POSITION TO THE ASSIGNED VALUE
    public int size() {
        return x.length;
    }                                             // RETURNS THE CURRENT ARRAY SIZE
    public double meanValue() {
        double meanDiv = 0;
        int div = x.length;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < div ; i++) {
            meanDiv += x[i];
            System.out.println("Testing");
        }
        meanDiv = meanDiv/x.length;
        return meanDiv;
    }                                       // RETURNS THE MEAN VALUE OF THE WHOLE ARRAY-------------
    public long median() {
        return -1;
    }                                          // RETURNS THE MEDIAN VALUE OF THE WHOLE ARRAY-------------
    private void dynamicInAction() {
        if (x.length == size) {
            long[] temp = new long[x.length];
            for (int i = 0; i<x.length ; i++) {
                temp[i] = x[i];
            }
            x = null;
            //System.gc();   // Might be unnecessary
            x = new long[size+1];
            for (int i = 0; i<temp.length ; i++) {
                x[i] = temp[i];
            }
        }
    }                               // ENSURES THE ARRAY GROWS WHEN NEEDED
    public void reverse() {

    }                                         // REVERSING ALL POSITIONS IN THE ARRAY------------------
    public void clear() {                                                                                                          
       x = null;
       size = 0;
       x = new long[size];
    }                                           // CLEARS THE ARRAY



}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps you should provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, including the data you're testing

Comment: When you were testing, were their at least one element in the array?

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha That was the problem, accidently clearled the whole list. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an array with a size of 0 in the constructor. That means unless you reassign x to another array, it will always have 0 elements. Try passing in the size in the constructor like so:

```
public DynamicArray(int size){
  this.size = size;
  this.x = new long[size];
}
```

Also, in Java class names have upper-case letters for each word (notice DynamicArray not dynamicArray).

Comment: Thanks, was the problem. Is it a must must to have upper case or just a general thing?

Comment: No problem. Yes, all Java classes and interfaces have uppercase letters for each word. Camel-case is used for variables and methods.

Comment: Something like `private void dynamicInAction() {` perhaps? Which is called by `add`?

Comment: The dynamicInAction() method doesn't work because the loop-continuation conditions in the for loops are based on the original size of the array, which is 0, so they won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Your project works. Here is your code

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         dynamicArray s = new dynamicArray();
         s.add(1);
         s.add(3);

        System.out.println(s.meanValue());
     }
}
```

result:

```
2.0
```

So, you need add at least 1 element before calling "meanValue()"

Answer (score 0):

Those two methods in your class meanValue and last worked fine when i ran them.
These the sysout which it showed to me :

```
Testing
Testing
Testing
Testing
mean 3.25
last 5
```

The code which i used to create object of your class and use it.

```
public static void main(String ...args) {
        DynamicArray myArr = new DynamicArray();
        myArr.add(1);
        myArr.add(2);
        myArr.add(5);
        myArr.add(5);
        System.out.println("mean " + myArr.meanValue());
        System.out.println("last " + myArr.last());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are correct that you have initialized the size to 0. 
But that is not your real issue.

You have 2 main issues:

1) In your `dynamicInAction` -You never increase the size of the array in this method! You simply create a temp array of the same size, copy x contents to the temp, then assign x to temp, never increasing the size. You need a slight adjustment to increase the size while you create the new temp array. I am 'pre-incrementing' size to have the new value used when creating the new temp array:

```
private void dynamicInAction() {
    if (x.length == size) {
        long[] temp = new long[++size];
        for (int i = 0; i<x.length ; i++) {
            temp[i] = x[i];
        }

        //Just assign x to temp
        x = temp;

        //x = null; Unnecessary
        //System.gc();   // Unnecessary
        //Dont create another array, you already have temp..just assign it
        //x = new long[size+1];
        //for (int i = 0; i<temp.length ; i++) {
        //    x[i] = temp[i];
        //}
    }
}
```

2) Secondly you now don't need to increment size in the add method, just set the value:

```
public void add(long value) {
    dynamicInAction();
    x[size-1] = value;
    //size++; Unnecessary
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight and basic explanation! I got an error though with add: x[size] = value; has to be x[size-1] = value; or itd go out of bounds.

Comment: jeez im trying to get to a new line and it just posts my answer straight away.. was trying to ask in the same comment how x = temp; works, where exactly is the increase in the x array? Though it works i want to understand why

Comment: You are correct on the x[size-1]. I've corrected it in the answer.

Comment: You create a new  long[] called temp, copied all values from x to the new temp[]. Calling x = temp simply 'points' x to the temp. All variables are essentially pointers to allocated memory. When you created the new temp[], you are basically occupying memory space. Then you just point your variable x (of the same type: long[]) to that location i memory. The increase in the size of x was done when temp is created. Note the line: long[] temp = new long[++size]; Notice I pre-increment size (++size). That causes size to become size+1. You place the ++ first to so it is done before it is evaluated.

Comment: Hmm, I think i understand now! So in the "clear" method would i be able to clear the array in the same way? long[] temp = new long[0] and then x = temp; ?

Comment: 1) You need to first reset the size variable: size = 0; 2) Because you dont need to copy the contents of x in this case, temp is unnecessary, just assign x to a new empty array: x = new long[size]; (after setting size to zero). And you don't need to set x=null first, once you assign x to a new array, the old array is dereferenced in memory and will get garbage collected automatically.

Comment: That explains everything i need to know at the moment, thanks a lot for your time!